# Использование команд в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как правильно создать `Command`, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, текст улетал в `TextBlock` из `TextBox`. Пробовал, но не получалось. Решил понизить сложность и просто вывести `MessageBox`, но опять ничего

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SynchronizedText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Height="30" BorderBrush="Blue">
                <TextBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Resources>
            </TextBox>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="130" Height="30" CornerRadius="10" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SynchronizedText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox Text="" Height="30" BorderBrush="Blue">
                <TextBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Resources>
            </TextBox>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="130" Height="30" CornerRadius="10" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
            <Button Content="ПЕРЕСЛАТЬ" Width="130" Height="30" Margin="0,10" Command="{Binding command}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainWindowVM();
        }
```

BaseVM.cs:

```
class BaseVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

MainWindowVM.cs:

```
class MainWindowVM : BaseVM
    {
        private string _synchronizedText;
        public string SynchronizedText
        {
            get => _synchronizedText;
            set
            {
                _synchronizedText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SynchronizedText));
            }
        }

        public ICommand command { get; set; }

        public MainWindowVM()
        {
            command = new Command();
        }

        private bool canExecuteMethod(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        private void ExecuteMethod(object parameter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OK","OK",MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
    }
```

Command.cs:

```
class Command : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        Action<object> executeMethod;
        Func<object, bool> canExecuteMethod;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            executeMethod(parameter);
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `command = new Command();` - вы считаете это нормальной командой? Как минимум, где указание `executeMethod`? Погуглите реализацию `ICommand` и выберите себе нормальный, рабочий вариант, его и инициализируйте, ибо сейчас у вас просто каркас, без логики, а чтоб там логика была, вы как минимум должны передать туда `Action`, который будет записан в переменную `executeMethod` и уже он вызываться. И да, зачем вам тут кнопка? Достаточно поля, текста, и связи между ними.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ кнопка, чтобы научиться юзать 'ICommand'

Comment: Ну если чисто для тренировки, то как и сказал выше, найдите любую, готовую, реализацию команды и посмотрите, как она устроена. В двух словах у команды есть `Execute` (что выполнять) и `CanExecute` (можно-ли выполнять). Вот в первое вы должны указать метод (в вашем случае это `ExecuteMethod`), а второе обычно делают необязательным. В итоге, если вы передадите `Action` через конструктор вашей команде, то будет нечто на подобии `= new Command(x=>ExecuteMethod(x));`. Кстати, `MessageBox` является нарушением MVVM, ибо это View в VM слое, а эти слои не должны друг о друге знать.

Comment: На заметку: для `Mode=OneWay` не нужно указывать `UpdateSourceTrigger`, так как контрол не обновляет свой Source. Эта фича работает только для `TwoWay` и `OneWayToSource`. За факт обновления данных со стороны вьюмодели отвечает вызов `OnPropertyChanged()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот такая реализация команды:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        => (_execute, _canExecute) = (execute, canExecute);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter)
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Используется так:

```
public ICommand MyCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(SynchronizedText);
},
parameter => SynchronizedText?.Length > 0); // CanExecute, заблокирует кнопку, если условие не выполнено
```

```xaml
<Button ... Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

`parameter` служит для передачи параметра в команду, например так:

```
public ICommand MyCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    string text = (string)parameter;
    MessageBox.Show(text);
},
parameter => parameter is string text && text.Length > 0);
```

```xaml
<Button ... Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SynchronizedText}"/>
```

Сам `CanExecute` в этой реализации команды необязателен, поэтому можно просто вот так:

```
public ICommand MyCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(SynchronizedText);
});
```

Это будет значить, что `CanExecute` всегда `true`.

---

Немного подробней про `CanExecute`. Представьте что кнопка выполняет примерно такой код, просто для понимания:

```
var parameter = ...;
if (Command.CanExecute(parameter))
{
    Command.Execute(parameter);
}
```

То есть если метод `CanExecute` вернул `false`, сама команда гарантированно не будет вызвана.

А так же кнопка подписывается на событие `Command.CanExecuteChanged` и при сработке события проверяет `CanExecute` и меняет свой `IsEnabled` в зависимости от полученного оттуда значения. Поэтому если используете команду, управляйте `IsEnabled` только из кода команды через условие `CanExecute`.

Если взглянуть в `RelayCommand`, то можно увидеть, что событие `CanExecuteChanged` сделано как прокси-событие для `CommandManager.RequerySuggested`, а это событие вызывается при любом событии ввода - тык мышкой или при вводе с клавиатуры.

Но бывают ситуации, когда надо принудительно вызвать `CanExecute`, не дожидаясь ввода, чтобы улучшить поведение интерфейса. Для этого просто выполните в коде:

```
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
```

Comment: За рамками ответа: для того чтобы текстблок жил отдельной жизнью от текстбокса, просто заведите еще одно string свойство, отдельное. И привяжите текстблок ко второму свойству, а не к первому. А в коде команды просто присвойте строку из одного свойства в другое.

Comment: совершенно не понятно, ибо в понимании `ICommand`  ноль, как и MVVM. Я знаю, что мы чётко разделяем проект, но какие методы и классы использовать не знаю

Comment: описанный метод 'RelayCommand' имеет принимаемые параметры, но в `MainWindowVM` я не передаю их. Нужно как я понял событие и предикат какой-то.

Comment: @ aepot меня учили мусорить в классе окна или страницы, поэтому тяжело понимать, т.к я все сношу и по новой познаю

Comment: @gwgw с точеи зрения аргументов и параметров, у меня то же самое, что у вас в вопросе показано. Разница в том что я использую лямбда-выражение, а вы метод, это просто синтаксис и сути не меняет.

Comment: я не знаю какие параметрв надо воткнуть) что я должен вытянуть, я вообще ничего не понимаю, есть какие-то книги? по icommand реализации?

Comment: @gwgw а у вас в вопросе не `ICommand` разве? Это же просто `interface`. Чтобы понять как работает интерефйс, надо поизучать что такое интерфейсы, я полагаю. Хотите больше примеров, загляните сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+icommand